# Use RavenHQ or host Raven on your own server?

Tags: ravendb, ravenhq

Can you give me a hint a pros and cons on wheather to choose RavenHQ or host raven in our own server?

Facts

- Internet Web application (OLTP)
- 30 000 documents or records per month will be generated
- Approx. 300 users (data entry) simultaneously (maybe less but needs to scale up to 300 hundred if neccessary)
- 4 Admins for reporting and issues
- Will have to maintain end of day backup
- Will have to replicate to SQL or other RDBMS for reporting purpose
  (like Datawarehouse)
- Will enable Versioning Bundle for audit trail
- Absolutely critical in terms of loosing money if it doesn't work
- Working time from morning till afternoon

Please advise me for the most reliable and fast choice, I'm not considering the cost in this choice?

RavenHQ or host raven in our own dedicated Server?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend RavenHQ with a Replicated Plan due to your requirement that it was Absolutely critical to work. With a dedicated server you have a single point of failure so it goes down nothings is going to work. It supports your:

- backup requirement (https://ravenhq.zendesk.com/entries/24241973-Periodic-Backups-to-Amazon-S3-Glacier)
- has the Versioning Bundle (https://ravenhq.zendesk.com/entries/21336716-What-RavenDB-bundles-are-supported-)
- would easily support 300 simultaneous users
- 30k documents a month would be about 450megs of space a month which would be covered by the Gold and Platinum level plans.

Unsure what you mean by 4 Admins so I can not comment on that.

You would have to write your own data warehousing service as SQL Replication is not a supported plug-in but that would be very easy to do.a